# Backbone.js Dyanamic Models

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, backbone.js

I'm going to be creating a Web Application using Backbone.js.

I have a web service that will inform me of what fields I need my model to have, so with that in mind I cannot create a static model, in order to create a dynamic model for my application that changes when my web services JSON does, how would I go about doing this?

Would I be required to use model.urlRoot()?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **urlRoot** if you want to set custom url for model. For further information read [urlRoot backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot).

Answer (score 0):

Will you call the same URL, giving the fields you want as a parameter? If you'll do that, so you don't necessarily need to change urlRoot or anything else.

If you do this:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

It will be dynamic already. It will have all the properties from your returning JSON and it doesn't matter if it changes every time.

But you can change the urlRoot, if you want.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({urlRoot : '/books'});
```

You can even define it as a function, that will return different URL's depending on some condition you have, like:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : function() {
        return '/books/' + this.get("anyField");
    }
});
```